# CORS failes when using Docker containers for frontend and backend

Tags: python, docker, vue.js, cors, docker-compose

The following code is working great outside docker containers. Now I would like to add a container for the backend and another for the frondend. So I create two Dockerfiles (that are probably uninteresting) and the following docker-compose file. I change `axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/test')` to `axios.get('http://backend:80/api/test')` in the vue component. I'm able to ping the backend container from the frontend container and I'm able to receive the api result via curl.
**But** axios is not able to make this api request anymore. And in the firefox console I get the error:

```
Error: "Network Error"
Cross-Origin request blocked [...] Reason: CORS request did not succeed
```

But I'm able to run the backend outside docker at one computer in my network and the frontend at another. So Cross-Origin is no problem outside docker.
What's the problem here? I have no idea.

---

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    backend:
        build: ./backend
        container_name: backend
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        environment:
          - FLASK_APP=app/main.py
          - FLASK_DEBUG=1
          - 'RUN=flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80'
        networks:
          - some-net

    frontend:
        build: ./frontend
        container_name: frontend
        ports:
          - "90:80"
        networks:
          - some-net

networks:
    some-net:
        driver: bridge
```

---

### original code

**backend in python**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources=r'/api/*')

@app.route('/api/test')
def test():
    return jsonify({
        "foo": "bar"
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**frondend (only vue.js component)**

```
<template>
<div class="hello">
    <h1>Message is: {{ msg }}</h1>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
name: 'HelloWorld',
data () {
    return {
        msg: ''
    }
},
created () {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/test').then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.msg = response.data.foo
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Did you try using the `@cross_origin()` decorator as shown in the flask_cors docs for a specific route, instead of using the `CORS` object ? I'm just curious if that also fails

Comment: It seems this is something to do with docker setup since it works outside. Are you using a browser to hit the frontend service, then the backend service?

Comment: @NeilTwist Yes I have published port 90 of the frontend container and use firefox to a access http://127.0.0.1:90/. There I get the error message in the Console.

Comment: Ok, See my answer then.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It would seem that you are mistaking how to reference docker containers from outside all containers.

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/test')...
```

Should refer to where the docker container is listening. Inside a container, this would indeed be `backend`, but outside, i.e. in your web browser, it would be a reference to the host running the container, followed by the port. Since you've mounted it on port 80 on the host (and 90 for the frontend), you should update the `get` to :

```
axios.get('http://{hostname or ip}:80/api/test')
```

If it's all running on the same host, then you could use `127.0.0.1` or localhost for your testing.

Comment: The frontend container should communicate with the backend container, so I use the hostname `backend` because both containers are using a bridge network.

Comment: Yes, I can see <h1>Message is: </h1> but the message is not able to load, because of that cors error

Comment: The error in Firefox implies that the error happens in firefox? Can you see the network tab in the developer console?

Comment: No the error that I can see in the console comes from the frontend that logs the axios error with `console.log(error)`

Comment: Yes, but you should also be able to see the network request in the network tab.

Comment: Yes I'm able to see that. The Request header: `Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*`
`Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`
`Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3`
`Connection: keep-alive`
`DNT: 1`
`Host: backend`
`Origin: http://127.0.0.1:90`
`Referer: http://127.0.0.1:90/`
`User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0`

Comment: So, you can see that the request is coming from Firefox, so the reference frame for the request is the browser, which means that you need to refer to the service from outside docker.

Comment: That makes sence :D Thank you very much. I's working now.

Answer (score -4):

You can use "links" inside docker-compose.yaml. So it will look similar to this:

```
xxxdjango:
    image: xxx_django:dev
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
xxx_ui:
    image: xxx_ui:dev
    volumes:
       - ./xxx_ui/src:/app/src
       - ./xxx_ui/public:/app/public
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - xxxdjango
```

So after this, you can use for Vue js

```
devServer: {
   proxy: 'http://xxxdjango'
}
```

and

```
axios.get('/api/test')
```