# How to connect angular frontend hosted on tomcat running in docker container to springboot backend also running in docker container?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

I have created seperate containers for angular frontend, springboot backend, MySQL db and have put them in same network created by me.
All this containers are in Linux machine.I am accessing this Linux machine from my laptop and putting <linux_macgine's_nane>:portnumber in my laptop browser for acccessing frontend. Portnumber is the on which I have binded to frontend container.
Angular frontend is hosted in tomcat server and springboot is using embedded tomcat server.
I want to find explaination  for following:-

1. When I am giving db container's name in database server URL in backend app, then backend container is connecting to db properly. But when I an giving backend containers name in frontend container for connection it is showing name cannot resolve error in browser's console.

But in docker docs they have mentioned when in user defined network container can communicate with each other by their name and also it is working for backend app and db.

2. error : access control allow origins header is not present in requested resource

After trying above things I decided to give Linux host' name and port to which backend app is binded in frontend app for connecting frontend and backend. But when I do that I am getting CORS error which says access control allow origins header is not present in requested resource.
But in backend logs I can see that dispatchservlet is initialized. And I have also created Corsfilter class for filtering and app is working fine when I run it in development using ng s command. But in docker container I am getting cOrs error mentioned above.

Am I doing things correctly or is it matter of tomcat server like tomcat itself is not allowing frontend to connect to backend.because headers I am getting in response are completely different than the ones which I am sending from backend in Corsfilter class.
And also When I put logging lines in Corsfilter class method they are not getting printed, so I think control is not reaching till my Corsfilter.

Please explain these things to me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are hitting the lovely CORS problem.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309527/cors-failes-when-using-docker-containers-for-frontend-and-backend?rq=1

In simple terms (A) is trying to call (B), but (A) has address (aaaa:8080), and (B) has address (bbbb:8080), so they have different HOST_addresses.  This is a simplification

Comment: Hi Susan, in this link they have given backend container name as server url in frontend github.com/techtter/scrum-board. And I have tried it and it works.   You should check frontend.conf file. It is for nginx config.