# CORS Error .Net Core Service In Docker Container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have a .net Core service that I want to call from a react app.  I have Cors enabled in the service and can see the headers being passed when I run from VS with Kestrel.  I can call the service from the react app and kestrel without a problem and can see the CORS headers come across and the preflight calls work.  However, when I containerize this service and run from Docker I am getting a CORS error when calling the containerized urls. I have Swagger configured so I can browse the service and make calls no problem from to the container.  I changed my CORS policy to be wide open for testing but still receive the issue.

```
builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()
```

Any ideas?

Tried opening CORS policy, tried changing the Docker variables

Comment: can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310156) help you?

Comment: I was able to get this working with a nginx reverse proxy but still feel like I shouldnt have to do that.

Comment: @TinyWang thanks, calling correctly already, can hit the service methods no problem with curl, swagger and postman, can also hit the service in the react app just cors error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved by `docker compose build` command.
This is all because Docker does not update images every `docker compose up` command.

From [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/):

> If you change a service’s Dockerfile or the contents of its build directory, run docker compose build to rebuild it.

Comment: just spends hours because fo this 
Thanks